# Is there a characterization of which posets arise as the transitive closure of a set?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I'm self-studying Kunen's "new" Set Theory and I just got to the transitive closure of a set. 
This is (somewhat abusively) defined as the sets below $x$ in the transitive closure of $\in$.
The example given (shown below) is a lattice, and this got me wondering if $\text{trcl}(\{x\})$ is always a lattice with top element $x$ and bottom element $\emptyset$.

I have convinced myself that this *probably* isn't the case<sup>1</sup>, but it did get me wondering if there *is* a characterization of which posets can arise as $\text{trcl}(x)$. I suspect that is too complicated a question, so I would be happy for partial results. I suspect there are lots of posets and lattices which we know can be *embedded* into $\text{trcl}(x)$ for some $x$, for instance.

---

Here is the lattice

[image: \text{trcl}({(1,2)})]

1. Say $x \cap y = \emptyset$, and $z \neq \{x,y\}$. Then if $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ are both in the transitive closure of some set, $x$ and $y$ might not have a well defined join

---

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Do you know Mostowski's collapse lemma?

Comment: What does $\langle 1,2 \rangle$ mean here?

Comment: It means the [Kuratowski Ordered Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition). So $\langle 1, 2 \rangle = \{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I actually got there in Kunen today! It certainly provides an answer - the posets of the form $\text{trcl}(x)$ are exactly those posets coming from well-founded, extensional relations. Is that correct?

Comment: That said, I would still love more information regarding which lattices and posets can be _embedded_ in $\text{trcl}(x)$ for some $x$, which I also mentioned in the question. It's possible my unfamiliarity with the subject is showing, but from only what I know about Mostowski Collapse I don't see what it says about that case.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Every well-founded (= no infinite descending sequence) partial order can be embedded in some $tcl(x)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber if you post that with a proof sketch I'll accept it ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Belatedly expanding on my comment above:*

We can show by a variation of the proof of Mostowski's collapse lemma the following:

> If $P$ is a well-founded partial order then there is some set $X$ such that the membership relation restricted to elements of $X$ is isomorphic to $P$.

In particular, this means that every well-founded partial order embeds into $trcl(\{x\})$ for some $x$.

Suppose $P$ is well-founded. Mostowski would have us consider the map $\rho$ defined recursively by $\rho(p)=\{\rho(q): q<_Pp\}$. This recursive definition makes sense because $P$ is well-founded. However, it doesn't behave well in this context since $P$ may not be **extensional**: $\rho$ will not in general be injective.

Instead we have to fold in some additional "labelling." Fix some bijection $b:P\rightarrow A$. We define the map $\rho^b$ recursively by $$\rho^b(p)=\{\rho^b(q): q<_Pp\}\cup\{b(p)\}.$$ The map $\rho^b$ is clearly injective, and we have $$p<_Pq\leftrightarrow \rho^b(p)\in \rho^b(q).$$ So we just need to check that we don't have any unwanted elementhood-nesses. Of course we **might** if we pick the labelling function $b$ poorly. So we have to go back and be more careful about our $b$: we want a set $A$ which is "totally unrelated" to $P$ so that no annoyances will crop up. One choice which will work is to take an $A$ whose elements are each cardinals greater than $\vert P\vert$; the point then is that the elements of $A$ are so big that we can't "accidentally" build one of them via the recursive construction of $\rho^b$.

Comment: Belated but welcome ^_^. In particular using big labels to avoid accidentally breaking things is a memorable trick that I don't know if I would have come up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial answer: To see an example where $\text{trcl}(\{x\})$ is not a lattice, consider

[image]

Then $2$ and $\{1\}$ have no meet, because their upper bounds do not have a least element.

Comment: This diagram seems to require $1=\{0,\{0\}\}$. It might be better to call it $2$.

Comment: @DavidHartley Ah yes, you're absolutely right, thanks! While we're at it, I should call $1=\{0\}$, which is what I had in mind too.